# FFMPEG command not working on MP4 files as expected

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to set the output time offset for mp4 file.

```
ffmpeg -ss 13.554000 -i input.mp4 -c copy -t 10 -output_ts_offset 13.554000 output.mp4
```

This code works for WEBM file as expected but not for MP4.
In webm it delays start time of video to the specified timestamp and duration is 23.554 but in mp4 it just cuts the video, start time is set to 0 and duration is 10 
Cannot find what is problem.

````
ffmpeg -ss 12.960000 -i v.mp4 -c copy -t 10  -output_ts_offset 12.960000 output.mp4
ffmpeg version git-2019-12-26-b0d0d7e Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.2.1 (GCC) 20191125
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig
 --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb
 --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora
 --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp
 --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis
 --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid
 --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth
 --enable-libopenmpt --enable-amf
  libavutil      56. 37.100 / 56. 37.100
  libavcodec     58. 65.100 / 58. 65.100
  libavformat    58. 35.101 / 58. 35.101
  libavdevice    58.  9.101 / 58.  9.101
  libavfilter     7. 69.101 /  7. 69.101
  libswscale      5.  6.100 /  5.  6.100
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'v.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    creation_time   : 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z
    encoder         : Lavf53.24.2
  Duration: 00:00:29.57, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1421 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1032 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, 5.1, fltp, 383 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Output #0, mp4, to 'output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.35.101
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 1032 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 12800 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, 5.1, fltp, 383 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=  250 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=    1687kB time=00:00:09.99 bitrate=1382.7kbits/s speed=2.21e+03x
video:1212kB audio:468kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.408804%```
````

Comment: Could you please elaborate? What happens? What's the output?

Comment: In webm it delays start time of video to the specified timestamp and duration is 23.554 but in mp4 it just cuts the video, start time is set to 0 and duration is 10.

Comment: Please add this to your question description.

Comment: Share full log for MP4 attempt.